# Common Query for mysql and sqlserver to retrieve top 1 record

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I've a sql query, which works perfectly in SQL Server, to arrive the last purchase rate of an item supplied by a particular supplier as :

```
Select  Top 1 Rate
   From   TXPurchaseDetail
   Where  CompanyCode     = 200
   And    VoucherSeries   = 'INPURSCR'
   And    SupplierCode    = 1042
   And    ItemCode        = 1521
   And    voucherdate    <= '2011/05/25'
   Order  By voucherdate desc, vouchernumber desc ;
```

Now, I'm converting the whole application which will work in both sql server and mysql.  In mysql the 'TOP' parameter isn't working.

How to make it to work on both database servers ?  Any help please.

Regards
Vaishu

Comment: From where are you executing this query (PHP, ASP.net., Some SQL Console etc..) ? As I already pointed to in my answer MSSQL and MySQL use different Syntax for Limiting Number of results, so maybe you can alter the query in accordance to which DBMS software you are using in the application that is executing the query.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you use LIMIT. This query would then be written as:

```
Select  Rate
   From   TXPurchaseDetail
   Where  CompanyCode     = 200
   And    VoucherSeries   = 'INPURSCR'
   And    SupplierCode    = 1042
   And    ItemCode        = 1521
   And    voucherdate    <= '2011/05/25'
   Order  By voucherdate desc, vouchernumber desc LIMIT 1;
```

Note the `LIMIT 1` in the end.
So you cannot have a single query for both MSSQL SERVER and MySQL, as both use different syntax for limiting the result set to only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

If "Top 1" just means return the first row, then "LIMIT 1" is what you're after in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Since the two platforms use different syntax for limiting rows, I suggest you consider implementing a stored procedure in each case, now the stored procedure code can use the appropriate syntax, and the application just calls the stored procedure - it doesn't have to care whether it's calling MySQL or SQL Server. This is one of the primary benefits of using stored procedures rather than riddling application code with ad hoc SQL.